# Why Goku and Vegeta didnt use Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken and Super Saiyan Blue Evolution to defeat Broly?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-movies

So in the new Dragon Ball Super Broly movie,

> Goku and Vegeta try to defeat Broly by fighting together in Super Saiyan Blue, but they dont use Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken and Super Saiyan Blue Evolution like they did to try to defeat Jiren

Why Goku and Vegeta didnt use Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken and Super Saiyan Blue Evolution to defeat Broly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSJB + Kaioken Transformation and the SSBE transformation were introduced by Toei and not Toriyama. Although the movie is being produced by Toei, they probably have less influence on the movie unlike the show.

Secondly(Note: This is a personal opinion), the movie is mainly focused around SSJB Gogeta defeating Broly. Hence, having Goku/ Vegeta use SSJB +Kaioken and SSBE would in a way disturb the flow of the movie. In the sense, it has been revealed that Gogeta is slowly going to ascend from transformation to transformation and fight Broly. Having the two additional transformations would disrupt this flow and at the same time might overscale Broly a little too high. Plus, if you look back at Goku/ Vegeta vs Merged Zamasu, Goku doesn't really go Kaioken at all in the Goku Black arc(Despite being overpowered)(Except the 1 time to break out of Merged Zamasu's hold). Then we see Vegito Blue in action.

Answer (score 0):

as far as, we were aware. we have seen nothing indicating that we will see **blue evolution** in the movie that's does not mean we won't see it because it's unlikely TOI have released all the information regarding the movie and not shown anything regarding super safe through evolution. so, we'll taking about whether or not reprise this transformation in the future dragon ball or be aiming for something else entirely to compete with those whose potential **ultra instinct** transformation we all know at some point you will get back but before we begin a quick in past fight of dragon ball super. Goku fought with Jiren in super Saiyan blue and kaiken but all in vain and finally he used ultra instinct with this he was nearer/definitely to Jiren defeat. in all the series and movies the new villain is stronger than previuos one. I know you all are thinking ,Jiren is not a enemy but he is main thread to universe 7. this shows broly is much stronger there will no need of SSB or SSB kioken

Comment: Some people have released scripts of the movie, they could watch it in a special event or something like that in Japan. If what they said it's true, it's confirmed blue evolution and kaioken wont be in the movie. It could be due to they were transformations created for the anime and not created by Akira Toriyama, but nobody confirmed that. If that's the case, in every story where Akira has full input over the story we wont see these transformations, unless he changes his mind and decides to incorporate elements he didnt create into his storytelling (like he did with Broly, for example)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for Kaioken not being used is because both Goku and Vegeta mastered SSB. That's why you see red flames and a dark blue aura around both Goku and Vegeta and even Gogeta, so since they mastered that form there's no need for Kaioken to be added, just like when Goku mastered Super Saiyan he didn't need to use Kaioken to boost his power level with his mastery of that form he's stronger now than with Kaioken added.