# Why didn't Vegeta use Super Saiyan Blue Evolution transformation in the Dragon Ball Super: Broly movie?

Tags: dragon-ball-series

In *Dragon Ball Super: Broly* movie, Vegeta did not use his Super Saiyan Blue Evolution transformation which looks like below.

[image]

Why didn't Vegeta use it?

Comment: Yea true, But it seems odd not for Vegeta to use that form once more , But on an up note he achieved ssjg does that mean if he does what Goku did with something like a spirit bomb or some other "New attack" He could achieve Ultra Instinct?

Comment: Related: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/49702/why-goku-and-vegeta-didnt-use-super-saiyan-blue-kaioken-and-super-saiyan-blue-ev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well firstly, the form is called *Super Saiyan Blue Evolution* and it is Vegeta's comparable form to that of Goku's *Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken*

As for why it wasn't in the movie, there is no definite reason as we don't see any comments from the staff with regard to the same. However, there are several reasons why this could be the case, for instance

- Due to the limited amount of time, there wasn't sufficient time to showcase as many transformations.
- Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken and Super Saiyan Blue Evolution weren't created by Toriyama.
- Keeping in mind the audience for the movie, it wouldn't have made as much sense if they had Goku and Vegeta use 2 random transformations and then fuse into Gogeta and use Super Saiyan Blue instead of the other transformations.
- Even from a story perspective, Vegeta and Goku weren't pushed to the same extent they were against Jiren. We don't know whether Vegeta can still tap into the transformation etc.

In the manga we see Mastered Super Saiyan Blue Goku/Vegeta fighting Broly and it was stated that the movie was a continuation of both the manga and the anime. So yes! There is no definite way to conclude why Vegeta didn't use the transformation apart from speculating based on some of the facts which I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Contrasting [Gary's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/51085/2516), it is wrong. This form was created by Akira Toriyama but it's much different. In the manga, Vegeta did use this form to fight Jiren and it had more power. In the manga, it's much different. It's mentioned by Whis and Berus that Vegeta has evolved. In the manga, this form is called Super Saiyan Blue Evolved. In the manga, there's no X20 Super Saiyan Blue Kaio-ken, but there is something similar that has more power but lasts only a few 10 seconds. It has no name but Goku mentions saying "I'll push to my limit", basically Super Saiyan Blue Limited.

In the Broly movie, when Goku powers up to SSJ Blue, it looks exactly like this form. So Goku did use his strongest powered-up version of SSJ Blue but was not enough for Broly. You have to take note that the movie is like the manga.

As for Vegeta not using his evolved form is quite not answered, but could be it requires more God energy and time to use it which he did not have at that moment. Also, it shows that Vegeta was not able to use his full power. But according to reading a part in the manga, Jaco mentions, "Wow Goku, you're strong", Goku says, "Not really, I fought a Saiyan stronger than me named Broly", Jaco says, "Wow, sounds scary". Later Vegeta answered, "Yeah, but we both easily defeated him". By the sound of this conversation, Vegeta and Goku both using mastered SSJ Blue easily defeated Broly with no fusion. The Broly movie anime exaggerated Broly's power and required fusion which kinda sucks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because Kakarot and Vegeta realised that a power increase of that scale wasn't enough and Broly would just adapt to the new strength. So they needed a greater difference in strength than x20 SSJB/SSJBE.